# Find duplicate entries on date and title

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I'm trying to identify duplicates in our database and I'd like to match on a combination of `f.[summary]` and `f.[date]`. 
 Since the dates aren't unique, I'm wondering if this is possible.  The way the query is written now, it will match only on `f.[summary]`

```
select
  f.[summary] as [Title],
  f2.[Possible_Duplicate_Count],
  f.[date] AS [Date],
  f.[type] as [Type], 
  f.[category] as [Category], 
  f.[status] as [Status], 
  (select u.[name] from [user] u where (u.[id] = f.[user])) as [User Name], 
  fp.[summary] as [Template]
from [form] f
left outer join [form] fp on (fp.[id] = f.[parent])
inner join
(
  select f.[summary], count(*) as [Possible_Duplicate_Count]
  from [form] f
  group by f.[summary]
  having count(*) > 1
) f2 on (f.[summary] = f2.[summary])

where
(
  (f.[parent] IN ('9e3c47d4-4f47-49bb-8ad4-4709c966ad38', '74069d7e-5ad6-4e7e-85f7-5402e67637ee'))
  and
  (f.[status] IN ('Confirmed'))
)
```

Comment: 1) Is the combination of date and summary unique? 2) is it a date or a date/time?

Comment: Please add a tag with your DBMS

Comment: Hi, neither the date or the title are unique.  I am trying to find events with the same title and same date.  Right now, the query is pulling events with just the same name, which arises the problem that it is pulling events with the same name, but happened last year.

Comment: Hi Joe, it's MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
f.[summary] as [Title],
f2.[Possible_Duplicate_Count],
f.[date] AS [Date],
f.[type] as [Type], 
f.[category] as [Category], 
f.[status] as [Status], 
(select u.[name] from [user] u where (u.[id] = f.[user])) as [User Name], 
fp.[summary] as [Template]
from [form] f
left outer join [form] fp on (fp.[id] = f.[parent])
where exists(
    select 'duplicate'
    from [form] f2
    where f2.summary = f.summary
    and f2.date = f.date
    and f2.id != f.id)
and
(
  (f.[parent] IN ('9e3c47d4-4f47-49bb-8ad4-4709c966ad38', '74069d7e-5ad6-4e7e-85f7-5402e67637ee'))
and
  (f.[status] IN ('Confirmed'))
)
```

Comment: Hi Joe, this throws an error: SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: 2 where statements: make the 2nd  where a 'and'.

Comment: @tonyweed: I've fixed my query

Comment: Is there a way to fuzz this such as where f2.summary is like f.summary ?  I've noticed some of our event titles have most of the words matching, but one might have an extra word

Comment: Fuzzy search could use Jaro-Winkler algroythm to do distance matching. http://dannykopping.com/blog/fuzzy-text-search-mysql-jaro-winkler  More here: https://github.com/fza/mysql-doctrine-jaro-winkler-function

Comment: @tonyweed: Link submited by xQert are very interesting!

Comment: Wow!  That is super interesting. I ended up using `like` to distinguish similarity, and it seems to be working well enough, but I'm definitely going to save @xQert 's link for future projects :)

Comment: @tonyweed: Good job!